# Why did Aizen kidnap Orihime in Bleach?

Tags: bleach

I remember that Aizen kidnapped Orihime but I don't remember if it was explained well why this happened. I have several hypothesis but not sure if they are true:

1. Was it that the Hogyoku didn't work until Orihime cured it some how? Was there such a scene in Bleach that gives evidence to this? Why wouldn't the Hohyoku work? Wasn't Aizen already giving more power to his hollows even before Orihime?
2. Is that why Aizen needed her or was it something else? To Maybe torture her to distract the Shinigami and Ichigo? But it seems that at this point he didn't really thought Ichigo mattered so it doesn't seem convincing.
3. Or did he use her to heal his Espadas?
4. Or did he do that to lure the Shinigami and trap them to Hueco Mundo?

Is there maybe another reason? Or are there multiple reasons combined? Aizen was smart so I am sure he had a reason to kidnap Orihime.

Comment: Probably a Lure, but at teh same time, Aizen was so strong he probably also did it as an experament and for a bit of fun. Who knows what would have happened if All captains and ichigo were in Karakura town when he invaided, especially if he brought 2-3 more Espada with him.

Answer (score 7):

The answer lies in Ichigo's existence. At the end of the battle between Aizen and Ichigo, Ichigo noted that Aizen's sword is filled with loneliness. Before Ichigo, there was no one of the same level of spiritual pressure as Aizen. This is proved in the conversation between Ichigo and his father, Kurosaki Isshin, on episode 301 of the anime.

> Isshin: Let's go (after Aizen)
>
>  Ichigo: Don't you feel it? There's no way we can fight such monstrous spiritual pressure.
>
>  Isshin: As I thought, you really can comprehend his powers.

That wasn't the exact words but is pretty much what they said in that episode. And previously during the battle between Aizen vs Isshin, Yoruichi, and Urahara, Ishin said that when he slashed Aizen, he didn't feel anything. Aizen felt so empty. This is because Aizen's power is far above Isshin, that Isshin can no longer comprehend (Isshin also mentioned this to Urahara after he unleashed Getsuga Tensho towards Aizen). This is later proven by Aizen when he made a normal human vanish just by being near him without the man actually understand that going closer to Aizen will kill him.

Why Aizen kidnap Orihime? The main reason is once again, Ichigo. Deep down, Aizen believed that Ichigo can reach his level. And to encourage Ichigo's growth, Aizen kidnapped Orihime so that Ichigo would feel the urgency of getting stronger.

The other, less significant (from Aizen's point of view) reason is Orihime's ability, Shunshun Rikka, which can negates reality. Aizen was curious about it when he saw Orihime used it to restore wounds.

As for Ichigo saying Aizen's sword is filled with loneliness, it was mentioned in episode 310 at 8:30-10:30 of the anime.

As for Yamamoto, he certainly was regarded as the most powerful Shinigami, but Aizen doesn't seems like seeing him as his equal. This is my own guess though.

Comment: Interesting. So, the part that confuses me a bit is, did Yamamoto have the same level of spiritual pressure as Aizen or was Aizen stronger? If Aizen was stronger, why did he even go through the bother to steal rijun jaaka?

Comment: Ichigo noticed the loneliness in Aizen zanpakto? When is this discussed in the anime? Was that in the very end battle when Aizen is sealed? I very curious!

Comment: He didn't steal it, he sealed it in Wonderweiss. I edited the answer to include your questions.

Comment: I wonder why Aizen never saw Yamamoto as his equal, that always seemed rather mysterious to me. Do you have any guesses?

Answer (score 2):

He kidnapped Orihime so he can wake up the hogyoko since Urahara sealed it. They said that the hogyoko will take a long time to wake up but with Orihime it took less time.

Comment: You're going to want to provide a source for this.

Answer (score 1):

Aizen understands her power and how it can basically reject reality / events that happened. He sees her healing ability as borderline God-like powers. Of course he values this and wants it to use as he desires. I think the best explanation of this is in chapter 240 page 7. I don't actually think he really ends up exploiting her abilities past what is in that chapter (healing Grimmjow).

Kidnapping her also has the added benefit of luring out Kurosaki and his crew. By luring them to Hueco Mundo, Aizen and his men get to fight on their own turf.

Comment: That chapter doesn't really explain *why* he wanted her kidnapped, though.  While I think you're on to something with the luring part, some more convincing information should be provided.

Answer (score -3):

I think its just a plot trick. Aizen has a big plan with a good story but the truth is that Ichigo had nothing to do with that. Author, instead of trying something believable, just pulled that cheap card of kidnapping Orihime so that Ichigo, the guy that has nothing to do there, does all the job and kills the main guy, again, who has nothing to do with him.

I remember that even there is a part where Aizen says that kidnapped Orihime because he was just curious of her mysterious power, but just that.

About the story of the above guy... Its an anime written for 15 year old kids, like Naruto, Dragon Ball, One Piece, etc, and like them, its full of plot holes. This is just another one.

Comment: how is this specific one (kidnapping orihime) a loop hole?